# Track task dependencies in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I have two tabs in my excel sheet.

**Tab 1**: Contains a list of all the dependencies across multiple functional area. The columns are functional area, dependency description, dependency id, plan end date, target end date.

**Tab 2**: Contains a list of tasks with the following columns:

Functional area, Deliverable name, deliverable description, Target Date, projected date, Dependencies ID

E.g.

```
Functional Area Dependencies  Plan end date  Target End date
   F1            D1            8/22           8/22
   F1            D2            8/23           8/23
   F2            D3            8/24           8/24
   F2            D4            8/25           8/25

Functional Area Deliverable Dependencies Target Date  Projected Date
   F1                de1       D1, D2        8/20           
   F1                de2       D1            8/20           
   F2                de3       D3, D4        8/20           
   F2                de4       D3            8/20
```

The Dependencies ID will contain all the IDs tied to a given deliverable from tab 1. The help I want is a way to find out that if any of my dependencies tied to a given deliverable have a date past the targeted date of my deliverable, my projected date should be populated to the latest date among all the dependencies. So in the above example, projected date for de1 should be populated to 8/23 and projected date for d2 should be 8/22. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: I'm working on something, but what would make it easier would be to have a third tab, called deliverable dependencies. This would have a single row for each, e.g. de1 | D1, de1 | D2 etc - is that possible?

Comment: Hi Cronan - So do you mean removing the deliverable - dependency columns and moving to a third tab? If it is just for calculation purposes, I can create another tab and copy these two columns over there. would that work?

Comment: Sorry, no, I meant another tab that would have two columns, Dependency and Deliverable. If de1 has two dependencies, this new tab would have two rows, with de1 repeated twice. What makes your problem really hard is the way the dependencies on tab two are compounded into one cell.

Comment: Yeah we can do that Cronan. I agree, thats why I have been struggling. Ideally this would be very easy in project but I am required to use excel.So what solution would you propose if we create a third tab the way you recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need three pieces to get this to work. the first is this formula (we're starting work on Tab2):

`=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(MID(SUBSTITUTE("," & C2&REPT(" ",6),",",REPT(",",255)),1*255,255),",",""))`

Cell `C2` contains the list of dependencies, e.g. D1, D2

Notice the 1*255 bit in the formula - if you change the 1 to a 2, then this formula gives you the second item in the dependency list, then the third, etc.

Now we have three formulas that will give you the first, second, or third dependency:

`=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(MID(SUBSTITUTE("," & C2&REPT(" ",6),",",REPT(",",255)),1*255,255),",",""))`

`=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(MID(SUBSTITUTE("," & C2&REPT(" ",6),",",REPT(",",255)),2*255,255),",",""))`

`=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(MID(SUBSTITUTE("," & C2&REPT(" ",6),",",REPT(",",255)),3*255,255),",",""))`

We're going to take each formula and wrap them up in a vlookup - this is going to look up the target end date from Tab1:

`=VLOOKUP(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(MID(SUBSTITUTE("," & C2&REPT(" ",6),",",REPT(",",255)),1*255,255),",","")),Tab1!$B$2:$D$100,3,FALSE)`

In this formula I'm assuming the data to be looked up is in `Tab1!$B$2:$D$100`, and I'm assuming the target end date is in the third column. Note this also assumes that the dependency column is column B.

This formula as is will give me the target end date for the first dependency.

We're almost ready to wrap these up into a single function, but before we do, we want to guard against vlookup errors:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(MID(SUBSTITUTE("," & C2&REPT(" ",6),",",REPT(",",255)),1*255,255),",","")),'Tab1'!$B$2:$D$100,3,FALSE),0)`

Now we can combine all three using the Max function, which will give us the biggest (latest) date:

`=MAX(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(MID(SUBSTITUTE("," & C2&REPT(" ",6),",",REPT(",",255)),1*255,255),",","")),'Tab1'!$B$2:$D$100,3,FALSE),0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(MID(SUBSTITUTE("," & C2&REPT(" ",6),",",REPT(",",255)),2*255,255),",","")),'Tab1'!$B$2:$D$100,3,FALSE),0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(MID(SUBSTITUTE("," & C2&REPT(" ",6),",",REPT(",",255)),3*255,255),",","")),'Tab1'!$B$2:$D$100,3,FALSE),0))`

Comment: This method doesn't require the addition of a third tab - please let me know if there's anything that isn't clear

Comment: Thank you Cronan. I will shortly give this a try and let you know it it works

Comment: Hi Cronan - The formula works perfectly, but is their anyway to make this formula dynamic because some function areas have 3 dependencies, some have 6, some have 8. And these dependencies can keep getting added, removed so need to make it dynamic in that manner

Comment: The best way to make it dynamic would be to change the format of your sheets: e.g. normalize the data, similar to using a database. Then you could make use of DSUM etc functions